# SVG transition in D3 very slow in webkit?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue. I am using basically identical code to the Pie Chart Update example for D3: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410

but on a page with many such SVG elements (think 100s). I am only transitioning about 16 at a time, but the transition lags and is noticeable choppy on Chrome/Safari. On Firefox and IE, they are perfectly smooth for even higher #'s of donut charts. Read some stuff into CSS3 transitions and transform translate3d to improve performance but I'm not sure if that applies here...any ideas?

Cheers,

Sleepy

Edit: Perhaps I should also mention the initial rendering of the paths takes considerably longer in Chrome/Safari as well...maybe as much as 8-10x.

Comment: Yes, you'll get that with many elements on the page.

Comment: Is this something that is specific to webkit though? I guess I will have to reduce the # of SVG elements...strange that it affects the transitions though when I'm only transitioning a very small subset.

Comment: You'll get slowdowns in general. It may depend on the browser/webkit version as well.

Comment: Thanks. Will this also be impacted with simple HTML elements as well? I refactored things so that only the SVG images currently viewable exist and the rest are destroyed, but their HTML containers remain, and the animations are still slow.

Comment: Then it's probably the transitions that are slowing things down.